# How to use blobs or dataURL as src of a-frame or a-sky for 360photos

Tags: blob, aframe, src, virtual-reality

I'm working on a simple script to show 360 images in VR, while changing the image dynamically.
For the moment, the next-image source is set by a simple timeout (amongst 4 local .jpg), but I'm planning to GET images from a remote camera, and then update the a-sky view every x seconds.

I was able to change the a-sky src attribute and set a different n.jpg. 
But I wasn't able to set a blob as source.

For now I'm just converting a local jpg to a blob but the next step is to ask the remote camera api to have the jpg binary, and convert it to a blob url.
Anyway, the new image is not shown.
It seems to be working only when you have a static content as src.

How can I do?
Thanks

Here part of the source:

```
      setInterval(updatePanImg, 2000);
      var seq = 1;
      function updatePanImg() {

          let blob_src;
          if (seq >= 4) seq = 1; else seq++;
          blob_src = seq + ".jpg";
          console.log('blob_src update ' + blob_src);

          //1-working (/imgname.jpg)
          //document.getElementById('asky').setAttribute("material", "src", blob_src);

          //2-not working (/blob:......)
          return fetch(blob_src)
              .then((response)=> {
                return response.blob();
              })
              .then(blob => {
                  let blob_src_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                  document.getElementById('asky').setAttribute("material", "src", blob_src_url);
                return blob_src_url;
              });
        }


<script src="aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-sky id="asky" material="opacity:1; src: 4.jpg" rotation="0 -130 0" foo></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Both of these look like they should work... could you say more about what isn't working with (2)? Do you see errors in the JS console? Ideally a live demo would be even better.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy no error in the console. You can see the snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/w1z5kgc3/9/

Comment: Tried also changing the standard 'src' tag instead of the material, but the behavior is the same. It doesn't like data urls..

Comment: In my experience data urls (e.g. `setAttribute("src", "data:image/...;base64,...")`) seem to work, but I couldn't get blobs to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in `url()`, maybe? As long as the blob starts with like data

```
document.getElementById('asky').setAttribute("material", "src", `url(data:image/png;base64,${blob_src_url})`);
```

Add the `data:image/png;base64,` or whatever the format is if it isn't there already.

Comment: I tried also putting the url(..) but nothing changes.
I also tried to change a 'normal' src tag (and not the material one), but the behavior is exactly the same. It works only with static content (n.jpg).
See here:  https://jsfiddle.net/w1z5kgc3/9/

Comment: What is the blob? I get blob:https://fiddle.jshell.net/a00c79ac-7ec6-a240-92cd-baf61f5ed061 which isn't a blob. And the url 404s.

Comment: The blob (intended as objectURL) is generated by the interval, the url is something like: blob:https://fiddle.jshell.net/b945880e-a4fd-4d7a-af1f-d5841653d61f (see in the console)
and is valid only in the DOM in which was created. I've been using blobs several times, especially with <img>, but in this case I'm not able to make the a-sky refreshing (with the new image).